# Extract intent details in Android from DEX file

Tags: android, android-intent, dex

I'd doing inter/intra-app analysis, where I have access only to APKs, and extracted their **DEX** files, so I don't have the source code of the Apps. I can extract **intent filter** details from the **manifest** file. In order to identify the inter/intra-app communication, I need to extract also **intent** information (`sender component which fires the intent, receiver component in case of explicit intent, action, data, category,etc..`), which is declared in the code. So can you please advise me how to extract this attributes from the DEX file. Where currently I can extract the intent action by iterating over obtained strings from the DEX file through `insn_const_string`

Comment: There is no way to reliably determine those sorts of details in every case. You may be able to do some static analysis to determine this for a subset of cases, but it's going to be.. non-trivial.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do, performing static analysis. But still I need to do some customization on the to fit my analysis purpose.